# Browser based (free to use) SSH

Tags: asp.net, ssh, ssh-keys, net-ssh

I have a commercial product that allows users to connect to various SSH end-points. Currently these users are forced to download and use Putty... Seems pretty straightforward, except that my SSH end-points require RSA/Private Key authentication. So now connectivity to these end-points is becoming a pain, because I need to explain to my users how to: 1) Download and configure Putty. 2) Manage, configure and use their PEM private keys.    I would like to make everything transparent by 'just working' through the browser. I own all information (both IP addresses and PEM connectivity keys), so is there such a thing as a browser based SSH that is both capable and can access RSA keys for connectivity?

Comment: Do you really want an online SHH client handling & storing all of your sensitive connection string information?

Comment: A Java Applet is run locally from the users' machines; nothing but the (signed) binary is stored on the server.

Answer (score 2):

MindTerm, from http://www.appgate.com/index/products/mindterm/mindterm_features.html , has a limited-use free license and supports the features you want.

JCTerm is completely free.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SSHtools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshtools/)? I think [GSI-SSHTerm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsi-sshterm/) is derived from it. GSI-SSHTerm is still actively supported as far as I'm aware. I supports the Grid Security Interface (GSI), so may have more features than you need.

Answer (score 0):

FireSSH is the best tool provided by Google chrome browser,install the firessh from the url,

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firessh/mcognlamjmofcihollilalojnckfiajm